# ERROR: identifier "img" is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I'm beginner to openCV. I dowloaded opencv2.4.5 and visual studio express 2012 then i followed this link http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html for setup everything in environment variable etc. Then i followed below link http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2013/06/load-display-image.html to create sample application. I included proper #include path. But i'm getting error.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <C:\opencv\build\include\opencv\cv.h>
#include <C:\opencv\build\include\opencv\cxcore.h>
#include <C:\opencv\build\include\opencv\highgui.h>

#include "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
     Mat img = imread("MyPic.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); //read the image data in the file "MyPic.JPG" and store it in 'img'

     if (img.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
     {
          cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
          //system("pause"); //wait for a key press
          return -1;
     }

     namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
     imshow("MyWindow", img); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

     waitKey(0); //wait infinite time for a keypress

     destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please do *not* use an absolute path for the includes, this is totally non-portable.

it should look like this:

```
// the usual suspects:
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"       // Mat is defined here.
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
```

also, to make this work, your "additional include folders" should point to "opencv/build/include"

and avoid the old c-api headers, like cv.h, highgui.h, cxcore.h

Comment: I'm getting cannot opensource file "opencv2\core\core.hpp"  for all those include lines..In "additional include folders" i used below line $(OPENCV_DIR)\include

Comment: so go and check if  $(OPENCV_DIR) points to right place. that may be wrong even. the files should be in "opencv/build/include"

Comment: I didn't understand. where to check?

Comment: This is the path C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core

Comment: yes. thus "c:\opencv\build\include" for additional includes

Comment: Does i need to use same in Environment Variable PATH?

Comment: I'm getting below error while run the project error LINK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d245d.lib. ' "C:\Users\Arun\Documents\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe" ' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program

Comment: so you made it through the compile stage, now come the linker problems. the  Environment Variable PATH comes later, when it comes to finding the dlls. its not related to your current problems. now you'll have to set the correct library path for the linker, ("additional library dirs" here)

Comment: also, no idea, why you are trying with 2.4.5. because some outdated blog said so ? 2.4.9 is out, and you should probably use that.

Comment: My library is correct. I'm using 2.4.5 so in Linked Input i used proper one.

Comment: I installed 2.4.8. But i'm getting Error error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d248.obj'